# How to use Serilog.Enrichers.MassTransit

Tags: masstransit, serilog

I am using MassTransit 5.3.2, MassTransit.SerilogIntegration 5.3.2, and Serilog.Enrichers.MassTransit 1.1.0. I notice I have the possibility of adding the Serilog enricher in several places. Two when configuring the bus:

```
Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(fun config ->
  config.UseSerilogEnricher()
  ...
  config.ReceiveEndpoint(fun ep ->
    ep.UseSerilogEnricher()
    ...
  )
)
```

And one when configuring Serilog:

```
loggerConfiguration
  .Enrich.FromMassTransit()
```

Since I have found multiple ways without really looking, I guess there are even more.

I couldn't find any documentation on which to call (or whether to call it everywhere). Which of these are necessary to call to get the Serilog enricher working for all cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author here. Sorry about that. I sorta whipped this up in a couple minutes and never got around to documenting it.

`PipeConfiguratorExtensions` has a `UseSerilogEnricher` extension method on it. It can be attached to any place on the MT pipeline. But the `IBusFactoryConfigurator` is probably where you want to put it.

```
            configurator.UseSerilog(logger);
            configurator.UseSerilogEnricher();
```

Second, configure the Enricher wherever you configure Serilog.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the fast reply! Could you just briefly explain what the library is actually adding that I won't get with MassTransit.SerilogIntegration? And what does `Enrich.FromMassTransit()` actually do?

Comment: It grabs a bunch of stuff from the active MT Context when logging. Stuff like `ConversationId`, `RequestId`, `ResponseAddress`, etc. These normally get logged by MT when MT logs messages, but this enriches messages you yourself log during the execution of a Consumer. It flows it down the execution context.

Comment: So there are two configuration things you have to do: stick an item on the MT pipeline; and configure Serilog to care. The first captures the MT context information and stores it away in logical call context; the second enriches logged messages with that captured information.

Comment: And those two items are the `UseSerilog` and `UseSerilogEnricher` calls you mention in your answer?